# Скрыть пункты элемента select

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть два выпадающих списка

```
<select name="type_id">
  <option value="1">Баннеры</option>
  <option value="2">Шманеры</option>
</select>
<select name="size_id">
  <option value="0">468x60</option>
  <option value="1">240x400</option>
  <option value="4">120x600</option>
  <option value="5">300x250</option>
</select>
```

Часть из опций я хочу скрыть с помощью следующего кода:

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByName('type_id').onchange = function changeSize()  {
      if (document.getElementsByName('type_id').val() == '2')   {
        var sel = document.getElementByName('size_id');
        sel.option[1].setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
        sel.option[4].setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
      }
    };
</script>
```

Почему-то абсолютно никакой реакции. Может так нельзя обратится к опциям?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName()` возвращает коллекцию DOM-элементов или по-английски `NodeList`, а не один элемент. Нельзя вешать обработчик на массив. Чтобы поставить обработчик события на все элементы коллекции, нужно пройтись по массиву циклом. Обработчик лучше добавлять через метод `addEventListener` или `attachEvent` (для IE). И зачем 2 раза искать одно и тоже:

```
document.getElementsByName('type_id')
```

создайте переменную и присвойте ей эту строку. А еще лучше, передать объект события (`event object`) в обработчик и вытащить из него `target` (`target` ссылается на элемент, к которому был привязан обработчик).

---

И кстати, firebug еще никто не отменял.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а чем firebug поможет? Я им только ошибки js смотрю

Comment: в firebug можно отслежить результаты тех или иных вызовов функций javascript и не только. это полноценный отладчик. и @Lucky думаю имеет ввиду что можно было избежать ошибки с неверной интерпритацией результата getElementsByName

Comment: В firebug, как и в chrome developer tools кроме самой консоли есть еще отладчик (в chrome вкладка Sources, в firebug вкладка Сценарий), где можно дебажить JavaScript. Если не умеете работать с отладчиком, то можно выводить значения через console.log() в консоль.

Answer (score 2):

Скрыть опции кроссбраузерно к сожалению нельзя, можно только удалить ненужные, а затем снова добавить.

Comment: Может и так, но у меня даже hidden к опциям не добавляется... Сейчас попробую удалить

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/TyFqy/1/)

HTML

```
<select name="type_id" id="type_id">
  <option value="1">Баннеры</option>
  <option value="2">Шманеры</option>
</select>
<select name="size_id" id="size_id">
  <option value="0">468x60</option>
  <option value="1">240x400</option>
  <option value="4">120x600</option>
  <option value="5">300x250</option>
</select>​
```

JS

```
var type_id = document.getElementById("type_id");

type_id.onchange = function ()  {
  if (type_id.options[type_id.selectedIndex].value == '2')   {
      var sel = document.getElementById('size_id');
      sel.options[1].setAttribute('disabled', true);
      sel.options[3].setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
  };​
```

CSS

```
select option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}​
```

Comment: Не знаю как насчёт getElementById(), но с getElementsByName() не выходит. Возможно по причине указанной @Lucky

Answer (score 0):

[@co11ter](/users/8357/co11ter), а ещё в firebug есть консоль, в которую можно выводить результаты и даже целые объекты, что бы просматривать их поля и методы. Как то вот [так](http://clip2net.com/s/2El5b).